# which event should I use to fetch web address from address bar

Tags: jquery

I Want whenever I change my browsers web address from address bar.
I want to fetch new address from address bar in alert box and ask to user want to continue if yes then i have to allow new address to load the content.

Which event should I use to grab new address from address bar whenever user changes his browser address.

Comment: onbeforeunload event??? But you can't get redirected URL AFAIK and for security reason, i guess

Comment: will it show new entered address to popup box

Comment: Like i said, AFAIK, no!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the `onbeforeunload` event:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Really leave?";
};
```

The browser will handle displaying the message with the relevant buttons, and either stay on the page (if the user chooses to do that) or leave it (if the user chooses to do that).

This is *very easily abused*. One of the few use cases for it is if the user has started doing something (composing an answer on SO, for instance) and tries to navigate away without finishing (posting the answer). And so typically you'd have a flag you'd check first:

```
var uncommittedChanges = false;
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (uncommittedChanges) {
        return "You have uncommitted changes. Really leave and lose them?";
    }
};
```

...where of course, code seeing the user start doing something sets the flag, then clears the flag again when the user commits the changes.

---

Re your comment:

> will it show new entered address to popup box

No, it won't. Or at least, I've never seen a browser that did. It's up to the browser what to show in addition to your message.

Comment: then how to fetch new entered address. Is there any way

Comment: @xrcwrn: None that I'm aware of. The address of the page the user is going *to* isn't really the business of the page they're going *away* from.